# Esconder o texto de um select

Tags: javascript

Tenho um select com uma pequena imagem e um texto em cada option. Quero esconder o texto quando abro o select e quando selecionar aparecer a option selected. Algo deste genero:

```
document.getElementById('select_lng').onchange = function() {
    window.location = "page.htm?lng="+this.value;

    document.getElementById('fr').style.visibility = 'hidden';
};

   <select name=lng id=select_lng>\n"
     <option id=fr title=FR  value=fr style=\"background-image:url(/logos/fr.png) >FR</option>
     <option id=en title=EN value=en style=\"background-image:url(/logos/en.png) >EN</option>"
  </select>
```

Comment: Seria isso: ?

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags

Comment: @akm você poderia explicar melhor a sua pergunta?

Comment: Por exemplo mudar a opacity para ficar so o texto na option transparente

Comment: Talvez ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13191/14262

Answer (score 0):

## "Quero esconder o texto quando abro o select"

Porque já não deixa-lo por padrão "escondido"? com este css é possível torna-lo invisível aos olhos pois o texto estaria com a mesma cor do fundo:

```
select option { color: #fff }
```

## "Quando selecionar, aparecer a option selected(selecionada)"

Automaticamente, quando você o seleciona, ele fica com o fundo azul, então o texto branco no fundo azul irá aparecer, por isso não precisaria de nenhum tipo de código para o feito.

## Exemplo:

```css
select {
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
select option {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
   <select name=lng id=select_lng>\n"
     <option id=fr title=FR  value=fr style="background:url(http://gartic.com.br/imgs/mural/ma/maquitinho/bandeira-da-franca.png) no-repeat transparent scroll center center / contain" >FR</option>
       <option id=en title=EN  value=en style="background:url(http://www.webbusca.com.br/atlas/bandeiras/eua.gif) no-repeat transparent scroll center center / contain" >EN</option>
  </select>
```

### Observações

Coloquei a altura e a largura definida do select apenas para melhor visualizar, e também, alterei o link das imagens para imagens na web assim possibilitando melhor visualização, e também adicionei modificadores ao atributo `background` como o `contain` e o `scroll center center` para centralizar a imagem e restringir a imagem ao tamanho da option, também, para melhor visualização.