# Largura do <option> dentro do <select>

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Possuo um `<select>` onde os textos que estão nos `<option>` são muito grandes.
Ao expandir o `<select>` na tela os opções saem para fora da mesma. Preciso de uma solução para o texto todo aparecer na tela, não deixando o `<option>` sair para fora dela.

Segue imagem do problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Os browsers não provêem suporte para formatações como quebras de linha, por exemplo, no elemento `<option>`.

Para resolver isso há diversas alternativas e truques.

1. Limitar o tamanho do texto.

   É o mais prático e simples.
2. Criar um script dropdown customizado

   Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162374/4793
3. Fazer uma gambiarra com options contendo valores iguais

   Exemplo

```html
<select>
<option value="1">Texto muito grande bla bla</option>
<option value="1">bla bla continua linha 2</option>
<option value="1">bla bla continua linha 3</option>
<option value="2">Texto pequeno</option>
<option value="3">outra opção</option>
</select>
```

A desvantagem dessa terceira sugestão é que visualmente fica estranho principalmente quando o usuário faz a escolha. Aí nesse caso terá que criar eventos JavaScript em conjunto com CSS para criar um visual mais adequado. O JavaScript seria mais para quando o usuário escolher, não ficar aparecendo apenas uma parte do meio ou do fim, mas mostrar automaticamente somente a parte inicial. Ainda assim, não acho que seja uma boa forma devido ao trabalho em formatar e adicionar scripts, etc. Um trabalho enorme para resolver algo simples.

## Radiobox com toogle JQuery

A melhor solução dependerá da necessidade do projeto. Talvez fique legal se apresentar as opções como radiobox (input type=radio) e colocar as opções dentro de um toogle do Jquery ou algo similar. Eu optaria por essa solução pois fica bacana e não dá tanto trabalho, além de poder criar opções com uma formatação customizada.

```js
$("#options").hide();
$("#select").click(function() {
  $("#options").toggle("fast", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">[Escolha ▽]</div>
<div id="options">
<label><input name="escolha" type="radio" value="1"> Texto longo, bla bla bal bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bala bla bal bal bal lna</label>

<br><label><input name="escolha" type="radio" value="2">opção 2</label>
<br><label><input name="escolha" type="radio" value="3">opção 3</label>
</div>
```